# What is the relation between dimension of eigenspace corresponding to an eigenvalue and the multiplicity of the eigenvalue in characteristic equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Suppose the Characteristic equation of a linear operator splits, i.e. $\operatorname{f}=\prod_{j=1}^{k}(x-c_j)^{d_j}$, where $c_j$ s are distinct eigenvalues of $T$. Now suppose $W_j$ is the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $c_j$. In general, is there any relation between $\dim W_j$ and $d_j$? I am having an intuition that $\dim W_j \leq d_j$. Is this correct and if it is, then why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly correct, and the equality of dimensions, $\dim W_j$ (the so-called *geometric multiplicity* of the eigenvalue $c_j$) and $d_j$ (its *algebraic multiplicity*) for all $j$ is criterion  for the diagonalisability of the matrix associated to the linear operator.

One  reason for this to hold is that, denoting $A$ the associated matrix in some basis , for each $j$, we have a sequence of subspaces which ultimately stabilises:

$$\{0\}\subset \underset{\textstyle=\:W_j\strut}{\ker(A-c_jI)}\subset \ker(A-c_jI)^2\subset\dots\subset\ker(A-c_jI)^{r_j}=\ker(A-c_jI)^{r_j+1}=\dotsm$$
The  value  $r_j$ is the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $c_j$ in the *minimal polynomial* of the endomorphism, which is a divisor of its characteristic polynomial.

Now one $\ker(A-c_jI)^{r_j}$ is the *characteristic subspace* for the eigenvalue $c_i$ and one shows its dimension is the algebraic multiplicity $d_j$ of $c_j$, so
$$\dim W_j\le \dim \ker(A-c_jI)^{r_j}=d_j.$$

Comment: I do not know about Minimal polynomials ,can you give me an explanation that does not require any concept involving minimal polynomial.

Comment: I don't have one in mind at the moment, but it's not hard to understand this notion: by  *Hamilton-Cayley*,  an endomorphism (or its matrix) is a root of its characteristic polynomial, so it is a root of a polynomial of minimum degree (just as in the case of algebraic numbers). This polynomial is a generator of the ideal $\{p\in K[X]\mid p(A)=0\}$. Is it clear?

Comment: What is ideal?I am not aquainted to ring theory..........

Comment: A subgroup for addition, stable upon multiplication by elements of the fing. A *principal* ideal is simply the set of multiples of an element. It happens that  $\mathbf Z$ and $K[X]$ (K being a field) are rings with all ideals being principal (so-called PIDs) for the simple reason that both have a Euclidean division.

Comment: I have not yet studied Rings.

Comment: But you can make a euclidean division of polynomials?

Comment: Euclidean division means long division?

Comment: Division with remainder.

Comment: Yes so?........................

Comment: Using division, you can show there exists a polynomial of minimal degree which has $A$ as a  root and, more importantly, that all polynomials having $A$ as a root are multiples of this polynomial of minimal degree – in particular, the characteristic polynomial.